# Clojure Values in Clojurescript

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I am testing om (https://github.com/omcljs/om) and I don't understand whats happen here:

I have a Clojure code that consume a API and put data into a vector. Then in my ClojureScript code I try:

```
(def urls (map (fn [c] (get c :url )) billings))
(def n (first urls))

(println n) ;; correct value
(.log js/console n) ;; null
```

Someone can explain this behavior ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a REPL, then `println` will—assuming you haven't issued `(enable-console-print!)`—generally print to your REPL. But, `console.log` goes to your browser's console output.

When you invoke `(.log js/console n)`, the REPL only prints the return value of `console.log`, so you see `nil`.

Comment: Mike, I see null on browser (console). So how I can see this value on browser ?

Comment: It is making me wonder if `n` is handled differently when converted to a string for printing (in that you have some odd sort of object). If you do `(println (str n))` compared to `(.log js/console (str n))` do you get different results?

Comment: (println (str n)) print correct value and (.log js/console (str n)) print null (on browser)

Comment: Wow. How about the behavior of `(let [s (str n)] (println s) (.log js/console s))`?